# Appending to $(this)

Tags: jquery

Within a function loop, I need to traverse further into the DOM.

```
$('.panel_wrapper .panel').each(function(index) {
   // how can I append to this.  For instance another class = "foo"
   $(this) .foo  /* does not work */
```

This is similar to what I'm trying to do in a function

```
$(this) = $('.panel_wrapper .panel');
$(this) .foo
```

The following is a better example:

```
$('.panel-wrapper .panel').each(function(index) {
  $('.panel-wrapper .panel:eq(' + index + ') .collection_alt_thumbs img:eq(0)').css({"border-color" : "#9B9B9B", "opacity" : 1});           
});
```

Within the function there are additional operations that will be performed, not necessary after the first operation but after a conditional statement.  Can the following be performed:

```
$('.panel-wrapper .panel').each(function(index) {
   $(this)  ('.collection_alt_thumbs img:eq(0)').css({"border-color" : "#9B9B9B", "opacity" : 1});  
   // conditional statement 
   $(this) /* some other element */

});
```

Comment: append what? do you want to add a css class named "foo" to all the object that matches your first selector? Try to be more precise in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function:

```
$(this).find('.foo');
```

Comment: I'm not adding classes or id's, I'm trying to append another path to the destination.  For instance, I need to get the image of the second li.  There might be a conditional test which will require an opacity to change in the third image.  So once I have the $(this) other logic needs to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

To append a class you should use

```
$(this).addclass("foo")
```

it really depends on what you're trying to do
if you want direct access to the DOM element itself you shouldn't wrap it at all

```
this.foo =...
```

will add foo to the DOM element itself (inside the .each function)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append to the selectors (i.e. further limit the items selected) or append to the items selected? @Darin's solution will do the former; if you want to select more items and traverse over them as well you can do one of the following:

```
$('.panel_wrapper .panel').add('.foo').each(function(index) {
```

or

```
$('.panel_wrapper .panel, .foo').each(function(index) {
```